# Splitting input into integers

Tags: java

I am trying to split the input that I get through a scanner and split the integers inside the square brackets and put all of them into separate tree sets and perform operations based on the operators in the line. I am having issues with trying to parse the input and add the into the different tree sets, I keep getting `InputMismatchException`even after casting it to an integer. Would like to know where I am going wrong.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int times = in.nextInt();
        //iterate through number of times
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            int num = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(num)
        }
    }
}
```

The input I take in is

```
6
[1,2,3] + [1,4,5]
[5,4,7,11] - [5,7]
[1,2,3] * [1,4,5]
[5,17,51,2,51] + [1,3,12,5,44,66,82]
[7,13,23,11,10] - [11,13,14,7,8,9,10]
[7,13,23,11,10] * [11,13,14,7,8,9,10]
```

[Where my question is from](https://www.learneroo.com/modules/83/nodes/445#)

Comment: `i <= times` should be `i < times` since you are indexing from 0. Also in loop you probably should read entire line and then try to parse it.

Comment: I can't understand what actually you want.

Comment: I am unable to split the input that I take in as integers while taking note of the operators as I will need to perform some operations based on the operator. But i'm just stumped at how would I split the input I take into integers.

Comment: Use `in.nextLine()` to read the whole. Then you should parse the integers.

Comment: Are you always going to enter your input within square bracket? What output you are expecting out of `[1,2,3] + [1,4,5]`

Comment: @Kartic I'm expecting `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` sort of input as it's doing union and intersection mathematical operations.

Answer (score 0):

`nextInt` can't properly parse characters like `[`, `]`, `,` or `+` (if it is separated from number like `+ 4` instead of `+4` which would simply represent `4`).

That is why when you are trying to parse String like `[1,2,3] + [3,4]` with `nextInt` you are getting `InputMismatchException` because of `[`.

Probably one of simplest ways to parse your file is in a way like

```
int times = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();//nextInt will not consume line separator, we need to do it explicitly
for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    parse(line);
}
```

where `parse` method could be in from

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern
        .compile("\\[(?<set1>\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)\\]"    // match first [1,2,3] and place it in group named set1
                + "\\s(?<operator>[-+*])\\s"        // match operator, one of - + or *
                + "\\[(?<set2>\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)\\]"); // match second [2,3,4] and place in group named set2

private static void parse(String text) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.matches()) {

        String[] set1 = m.group("set1").split(",");
        String[] set2 = m.group("set2").split(",");
        String operator = m.group("operator");

        if (operator.equals("+")){
            //handle sum of sets
        } 
        //handle rest of operators
        else if (operator.equals("-")){
            //...
        }
        //...

    } else {
        System.out.println("wrong text format:");
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```